# Jenkins BlueOcean only to build using a single branch for build?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

When I build a multibranch pipeline job using BlueOcean it looks into my repository and reads all of my Jenkinsfile for each branch. to initiates multiple build, but I only want to be able to build a job based on a certain branch.  Is there a way to only build blueocean?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like your job is a Multibranch Pipeline.

If you create a job that is just a Pipeline (rather than Multibranch Pipeline), you can specify a single specific branch to build.